# Contentful API not giving expected results - Nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful

I am building a blog based off of this project here from Contentful using NuxtJS
https://github.com/contentful/blog-in-5-minutes

Here is mine: https://github.com/KyleTryon/VidFireBlog

I am currently experiencing two issues so far with retrieving data as they do in the example.

## 1. Not able to obtain images.

https://github.com/contentful/blog-in-5-minutes/blob/master/pages/blog/_slug.vue

In the example you can see the `headerImage` contains `.fields.url`
When I return in image on my project in the same way, there are no fields.

`{ sys: { type: 'Link', linkType: 'Asset', id: '1YADPXXX-' } }`

## 2. Filtering doesn't appear to work.

https://github.com/KyleTryon/VidFireBlog/blob/master/pages/blog/_slug.vue

This is again based directly off of the example linked above.

`return client.getEntries({
        'content_type': env.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
        'fields.slug': params.slug
      })`

This should only return entries of the type blog post. I have a v-for rendering each post. at the moment I only have two. I see a third  item on my page and after further inspection, i see that the third item is from the API also returning my "author" asset of a different type. This is also the only other published content I have. So it seems just all content is showing and the filter is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first issue, could it be your asset was not published?

for the second, you actually have a typo in your code:

https://github.com/KyleTryon/VidFireBlog/blob/master/pages/blog/index.vue#L63

`CTF_BLOG_TYPE_ID` should be `CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID`

All the best,
Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't explain why but the first issue seems to have solved itself. I could maybe go through commits to try and find out why but im just going to go with it.

Still an issue with number 2 at the moment.